# Unable to log in to Joomla! front-end

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, security, security-token

When attempting to log in using the standard [Joomla! login page](https://southernjanitorial.com/login.html), the following message is displayed:

> ### Warning
>
> The security token did not match. The request was aborted to prevent any security breach. Please try again.

There are no errors in the log file and all extensions are up-to-date. The only authentication plugins enabled are:

- Authentication - Joomla
- Authentication - Cookie

Disabling either changes nothing.
Disabling all extensions changes nothing.
Enabling all extensions changes nothing.

I'm using the "Amaze" template, but it does the same thing with both the "Prostar" and "Beez3" templates.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean you browser cache etc?

This warning always means that the token in the form is 
a) outdated --> reload of the webpage and cache cleaning helps
b) the form does not have a token or it's broken

- Do you have a link to take a look on it?
- Are you using the Joomla standard template?
- do you have any extensions active which are not Joomla core extensions?
- In short: more context would help

Can't write comments yet, that's why I ask in the answer section.

Comment: - https://southernjanitorial.com/login.html

Comment: There are about 215 non-core extensions (components, modules, and plugins) in use.

Comment: Short view didn't show any problem. You get a 404 as response on a login. 215 non-core extensions are a lot ... but it will be one of those. You could start guessing or make a dev copy of the site and deactivate all at a time.

Comment: 215 is not much. Some components like AcyMailing install 25 extensions. I manage other Joomla! sites with 539 and 786 non-core extensions. However, I will test if disabling any of these affect login abilities. I try to go for more direct solutions, first, without stabs in the dark, though.

Comment: Sounds good. I count extensions + subextensions as one ...

Comment: I disabled all extensions...same error. I enabled all extensions...same error.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is generally caused by some wrong settings in the configuration.php file - make sure that:

- The $live_site value is set to empty ('') or the actual live website.
- The $tmp_path is correct

The issue cause also be related to PHP permission issues, but most likely this is caused by a wrong value in the configuration.php file.